# синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "BurgerMaker", DrinkMaker, PotatoMaker, в месте добавления

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



class Cashier
{
public:
    Cashier()
    {
        _iBurgerMakerOerder = 0;
        _iDrinkMakerrOerder = 0;
        _iPotatoMakerOerder = 0;
    }
    ~Cashier() {}

    bool TakeOrder()
    {
        int iQuanBurgerTime, iQuanDrinkTime, iQuanPotatoTime;
        cout << "Кол-во бургеров: ";
        cin >> iQuanBurgerTime;

        cout << endl << "Кол-во лимонада: ";
        cin >> iQuanDrinkTime;

        cout << endl << "Кол-во картошки: ";
        cin >> iQuanDrinkTime;

        if (_take_order(iQuanBurgerTime, iQuanDrinkTime, iQuanDrinkTime))
        {
            _to_order();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:

    bool _take_order(int _b, int _d, int _p)
    {
        if ((!_b) && (!_d) && (!_p))
            return false;

        this->_iBurgerMakerOerder = _b;
        this->_iDrinkMakerrOerder = _d;
        this->_iPotatoMakerOerder = _p;

        return true;
    }

    void _to_order()
    {
        vector<Cashier*> cashierArray;

        cashierArray.push_back(new BurgerMaker(_iBurgerMakerOerder));
        cashierArray.push_back(new DrinkMaker(_iDrinkMakerrOerder));
        cashierArray.push_back(new PotatoMaker(_iPotatoMakerOerder));
    }


    int _iBurgerMakerOerder, _iDrinkMakerrOerder, _iPotatoMakerOerder;
};

class BurgerMaker : public Cashier
{
public:
    BurgerMaker()
    {
        _quanBurger = 0;

        _cook_burger();
    }
    ~BurgerMaker() {}

    void a() {}

    BurgerMaker(int value)
    {
        _quanBurger = value;

        _cook_burger();
    }

private:
    int _quanBurger;


    bool _cook_burger()
    {
        if (!_quanBurger)
        {
            cout << endl << " Жду заказ" << endl;

            return false;
        }

        cout << endl << "Готовлю " << _quanBurger << "бургер(-а, -ов)" << endl;
        cout << endl << "Заказ готов" << endl;

        return true;
    }
};

class DrinkMaker : public Cashier
{
public:
    DrinkMaker()
    {
        _quanDrink = 0;

        _cook_drink();
    }
    ~DrinkMaker() {}

    DrinkMaker(int value)
    {
        _quanDrink = value;

        _cook_drink();
    }

private:
    int _quanDrink;


    bool _cook_drink()
    {
        if (!_quanDrink)
        {
            cout << endl << " Жду заказ" << endl;

            return false;
        }

        cout << endl << "Готовлю " << _quanDrink << "лимонад(-а, -ов)" << endl;
        cout << endl << "Заказ готов" << endl;

        return true;
    }
};

class PotatoMaker : public Cashier
{
public:
    PotatoMaker()
    {
        _quanPotato = 0;

        _cook_Potato();
    }
    ~PotatoMaker() {}

    PotatoMaker(int value)
    {
        _quanPotato = value;

        _cook_Potato();
    }

private:
    int _quanPotato;


    bool _cook_Potato()
    {
        if (!_quanPotato)
        {
            cout << endl << " Жду заказ" << endl;

            return false;
        }

        cout << endl << "Готовлю " << _quanPotato << "картошку(-и, -ек)" << endl;
        cout << endl << "Заказ готов" << endl;

        return true;
    }
};

class MC_Donalds
{
public:
    MC_Donalds() {}

    ~MC_Donalds() {}

    bool act()
    {
        Cashier time;

        if (time.TakeOrder())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "russian");

    MC_Donalds q;
    q.act();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Препод сказал что бы функционал происходил в дочерних классах, от этого ни как не уйти. Помогите найти решение или исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри класса Cashier удалите тело функции `_to_order`, оставив только

```
void _to_order();
```

и перенести его прямо над main

```
void Cashier::_to_order()
{
    vector<Cashier*> cashierArray;

    cashierArray.push_back(new BurgerMaker(_iBurgerMakerOerder));
    cashierArray.push_back(new DrinkMaker(_iDrinkMakerrOerder));
    cashierArray.push_back(new PotatoMaker(_iPotatoMakerOerder));
}
```

также обратите внимание, что внутри main переменная `iQuanDrinkTime` скопипащена.

Comment: спасибо, заработало, могли бы вы пожалуйста поиснить данную ошибку ?)

Comment: "поиснить"? в точке использования сущности (класса) компилятор должен иметь достаточно информации о этой сущности. Он не может заглянуть на несколько строчек вниз.

Answer (score 0):

1. Я бы сказал, что  функция  `Cashier::_to_order()` вообше не нужна.
   Она ничего не делает кроме того, что  создает обьекты в куче и,
   следовательно, проблему. Вектор уничтожается сразу после вызова, а
   обьекты, чьи адреса  нигде не сохранены, остаются. Результат: утечка
   памяти, лишный вызов функции, когда можно  просто создать эти три
   обьекта.
2. Смысль наследования и функций теряется, если каждый раз код
   повторяется, что наблюдается у вас везде...

Comment: полностью согласен, это решение прподователя((